# Model over/under-fitting evaluation with chi-squared test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Here are some data: (R language)

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame( ins=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 100, replace=T), 
                  outs=sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 100, replace=T) )
df  <- ifelse(with(dat, ins-outs)>2, 3,
              ifelse(with(dat, ins-outs)< -2, -3,
                     with(dat, ins-outs)))
```

The `ins` column is the levels of in-sample data (model development sample) and `outs` is the levels from the model (fitted).

I would like to test for under/over estimation. To do so I would like to only consider up to -/+3 notch difference.

```
# calculate the frequency table
tab   <- data.frame(t(table(df)))[c(1,2,3,5,6,7), c(2,3)]; 
tab$p <- rep(0, nrow(tab))
tab$p[1:3] <- tab$Freq[1:3]/sum(tab$Freq[1:3])
tab$p[4:6] <- tab$Freq[4:6]/sum(tab$Freq[4:6])

# expected frequency 
tab$exp_freq <- rev(c(floor(tab$p[1:3]*sum(rev(tab$Freq)[1:3])),
                      floor(tab$p[4:6]*sum(rev(tab$Freq)[4:6])) ))
```

\begin{align}
&H_{0}: p_{-3}=u_{-3}, p_{-2}=u_{-2}, p_{-1}=u_{-1}  \\[5pt] 
&H_{1}: \sum_{i=1}^{3} u_{i} - \sum_{i=1}^{3} p_{i} > 0
\end{align}

where $p_{i}$ represents left side and $u_{j}$ right side.

This is the chi-squared test from R:

```
with(tab, chisq.test(Freq, p=exp_freq, rescale.p=TRUE))
```

Well, I'm indifferent, would this be correct approach given setup hypothesis?

```
# insert equal p 
tab$eq_p <- 1/nrow(tab)

with(tab, chisq.test(Freq, p=eq_p))
```

Comment: Aside from your R code it would help if you provide background  on your question.  Why do you think a chi square test is appropriate?  What did you calculate by hand that differs from the result in R?  You need more clarity or the question may be closed.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, thank you for looking into this. I ammended the question slightly, but overall I feel the question is pretty straithforward, with data and calculation disclosed.

Comment: I now completely redone the question, I believe this time is clear. Thanks.

Comment: "Checking the calculation" is typically going to be off topic here. (Moreover, R isn't going to make a simple arithmetic error, so it isn't clear what the point is.) Can you say more about what is motivating this question? Are you wondering if / how to use a chi-squared test to determine if a model is overfitting or underfitting?

Comment: Yes, I'm indeed wondering if / how to use a chi-squared test to determine if a model is overfitting or underfitting.

Comment: It might be better to start w/ the actual (or simulated) data & model fit, & go from there. This is somewhat ambiguous, & may be a wild goose chase.

Comment: thanks, nevertheless, how to use the chisq test in this case? I outlined two options, however not even sure whether one of them is correct....

Comment: @gung: do you mean the chisq test should be rather performed on the in-sample vs. fitted values rather as seen in object dat in data example provided?

Comment: I mean it is best to begin thinking about under vs over fitting starting from the original data & model, not data & predicted values divorced from the model.